# how to combine, .change(function() for two different type of input and send the values to same function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkbox sending value to this function called `sendtobox()` upon checked. That function makes ajax call to fetch data from database.

Now I want to have range slider of html also send its value to this function.

How do I do it please?

```
<script>
       $(".slider").change(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       sendtobox(value);
      });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval);
     }
      else {
        $("th."+selectedval).remove();//controls removing from boxA
     }
    });



</script>
```

How to alter above so that it sends like this `sendtobox(value1,value2);`

By Passing this together, I'm trying to achieve this:

The below function now must accept two variables which will be passed to `getsubjects.php`. In that php I'm retrieving the value like this:`$r= $_GET['r'];` to display in a textbox.

```
function sendtobox(param,param2)
            {
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              if (this.responseText !== null) {
                var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
                ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; // append in front
               }

             }
            }

                 xmlhttp.open("GET","getsubjects.php?q="+param+"r="+param2,true);
                 xmlhttp.send();

            }
```

### **EDITED**

Now I know that I can pass via string url like `this:xmlhttp.open("GET","getsubjects.php?q="+param+"&r="+param2,true);`

But the script is not passing the value correctly as I replaced `param2` value with digit 10, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, while making your ajax call, send the slider value while calling from input checkbox change and vice-a-versa. Please check if this helped for your solution.

```
<script>
       $(".slider").change(function() {
       var value = $('.slider').slider("option", "value");
       sendtobox(value, $("input[type=checkbox]").val());
      });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval, $('.slider').slider("option", "value"));
     }
      else {
        $("th."+selectedval).remove();//controls removing from boxA
     }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure a sit's not passing the slider value in a textbox as expected.

Comment: Im actually passing the value to the function, because that function fetches data from db for those checkbox value in a php page. In That php page has  textbox which will be shown on html. SO I want to display the slider value inside the textbox value

Comment: Are you saying that you are not able to get the slider's value as expected ? Can you please elaborate a little more about what are you trying to say ?

Comment: to put it simple,  in the getsubjects.php page I must get the value of the slider in this form $slider= $_GET['slider'];.....  How to do this, I thought I can pass it through the function but it seems not passing anything.

Comment: the value of slider I can get if I submit the form. But before submit, I want to get the value and display it on the textbox...I just wanna know how to pass the value to php page mentioned above via sendtobox() function

Answer (score 0):

Note, appear to two variables `selectedval` , `selectedtext` ; not certain if the value passed to `sendtobox` should toggle depending on `checkbox` being `checked` ?

Try

```js
function sendtobox(param, param2) {
  // do stuff with `param`, `param2`
  console.log(param, param2);
    /*
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText !== null) {
          var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
          ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; 
          // append in front
        }

      }
      
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getsubjects.php?q=" + param + "r=" + param2, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    */
}

var value = null
, selectedtext = null
, selectedval = null;

$("input[type=checkbox], .slider").change(function() {

  if ($(this).is(".slider")) {
    value = this.value;
  };
  
  if ($(this).is("[type=checkbox]")) {
    selectedval = this.value;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
    }
  };

  sendtobox(value, selectedval);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" class="slider" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">abc</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
       $("#slider1").change(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       sendtobox(value, $("input[type=checkbox]").val());
      });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval, $("#slider1").val());
     }
      else {
        $("th."+selectedval).remove();//controls removing from boxA
     }
    });
</script>




xmlhttp.open("GET","getsubjects.php?q="+param+"&r="+param2,true);
```